# terraform: How to override AWS RDS final snapshot

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Have the following DB resource in tf file:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "app_db" {
  count = local.db_count

  allocated_storage     = 5
  max_allocated_storage = 10
  engine                = "postgres"
  instance_class        = "db.t3.micro"
  name                  = var.db_creds["db_name"]
  port                  = 5432
  username              = var.db_creds["username"]
  password              = var.db_creds["password"]

  db_subnet_group_name   = aws_db_subnet_group.database_sg.name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.app.id]

  final_snapshot_identifier = "${var.environment_deployment_tag}-app-db-snaphot"
}
```

After destroying DB resource I get this error:

> DBSnapshotAlreadyExists: Cannot create the snapshot because a snapshot with the identifier app-db-snaphot already exists

I understand that it is because snapshot with such identifier already exists but I'd like to ask if there is a way to override previous snapshot?

If no and all snapshots should have unique name, I guess format something like this should be fine:
`final_snapshot_identifier = "${var.environment_deployment_tag}-app-db-snaphot-${timestamp()}"`

I wonder how to clean up previous snapshots so on RDS won't be a lot of them? And what is the best approach to manage final snapshot?

Answer (score 11):

If you do want to maintain a final database snapshot and use the `final_snapshot_identifier = "${var.environment_deployment_tag}-app-db-snaphot-${timestamp()}"` snippet, be sure to add this `lifecycle` block so that subsequent Terraform plans don't see a "change" every time due to the use of the `timestamp()` function:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      final_snapshot_identifier,
    ]
}
```

You may also need to replace the `:` characters from the `timestamp()` function with `-` characters by using `replace(timestamp(), ":", "-")` like so:

`final_snapshot_identifier = "${var.environment_deployment_tag}-app-db-snaphot-${replace(timestamp(), ":", "-")}"`

Comment: Best approach IMHO, op should mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

If you really do not need to have a final snapshot you can skip it using the following:

```
skip_final_snapshot  = true
```